# How do I 1: Extract horizontal lines of data into vertical range with headings. 2: Vertical range of said data, show only selected items

Tags: google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

I have a spreadsheet that I want to add data to as needed, and formulas to display it dynamically as needed.

Throughout, I'll refer to this spreadsheet which contains and example of my problem: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1maHGRearacPc4TOqiMShvjdP0oskOVMXb_X9mD9Cc6k/edit?usp=sharing
The spreadsheet is fully editable. So feel free to put your solutions in (though perhaps make duplicate pages so others card present their own solutions)

**Problem 1**: In the "Dynamic data" tab, I have a column with the names of an unknown number of groups (A2:A). Then to the right of each group name is it's data (B2:E).
I want to transpose each row into a vertical column, adding text next to each title.
In the example, F2 has the symbol I wish to add, G2 has where I would put the formula, and G2:G14 has the result I expect.

Notes:

- Though there are currently 3 groups (A2:A4) in "Dynamic data" the idea is that I should be able to add groups as needed.
- In the example, the data (B2:E) goes up to column E, but realistically the data would use many more columns.

UPDATE: **Extra (optional)**: Any empty groups such as "Group 4" get skipped when creating array in G2.

**Problem 2**: In the next tab "Extracting Selected Data", I want to be able to select specific data (B2:B), and have another vertical range displaying that data, divided by the group titles (F2:F). This range would skip any groups that don't have data selected. (ie. E,F nor G are selected, so group 2 does not appear)

**Extra (optional)**: B2:B has data validation, if possible, I'd like to only be able to select "non-titles" (ie. A,B,C,D,E...), but still have them visible in the data validation list.

UPDATED(No.2) **Problem 3**: If possible, having code which provides just the group headings that have the data selected, would also be amazing. It also means I can then create my own solution(s) to displaying data that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

Assuming the data starts from `Column B`

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY({F2&A2:A,B2:E},"select * where Col2 is not null",0)),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null",0))
```

---

**Problem 2:**
I think it can be done by a simpler regex or even only use regex.

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN("♦",QUERY(A2:A,CONCATENATE("select A where A contains '------' or A='",TEXTJOIN("' or A='",TRUE,B2:B),"'"),0)),"(-----[^♦]+♦)(-|$)|(-----[^♦]+$)",),"♦"))
```

---

**Extra:**

You cannot set a list of values and limit the input with formula simultaneously.

You may consider to use `onEdit` to reject input.

---

**Headings:**

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("♦",FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),"------ ",FALSE)),CONCATENATE("select Col1 where Col1 contains '♦",TEXTJOIN("' or Col1 contains '",TRUE,B2:B),"'"),0),"♦.+$",))
```

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("♦",TRUE,A2:A)&"♦",CONCATENATE("------ ([^♦]+♦)(([^-♦]+♦)*)((",TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,B2:B),")♦)(([^-♦]+♦)*)|------ ([^♦]+)♦(([^-♦]+♦)+)"),"$1"),"♦"))
```

Comment: Brilliant, the Array Formula works (Greatly appreciated), but the solution to problem 2 does not. I've changed the user selected data and you will see the error in the spreadsheet: If the selected data has a group above it with no selected data, it will show the heading for the above data, as well as it's own group. (See H2:H3 in "Extracting Selected Data")

Though I was able to copy your code (with the mentioned error) across to my main spreadsheet and replace the input accordingly, it seemed to work fine otherwise

Comment: Corrected. Please check.

Comment: If you see this, and you're willing, would you also be able to add code to present a range of group headings with data selected in them. e.g. If the user selects H,J and O, this range would show "Group 3" and "Group 5" without the "------".

I realize this is an extra request, so don't feel you have to, it would just be helpful if you're willing, as your code is beyond me :P

Comment: Do you mean to output `Group3` and `Group5` in a column? Are you asking for a formula referring to the solution of problem 2, or a standalone formula?

Comment: This formula I'm asking for is a new one, separate to problem 1 and 2. Let's call this formula "Headings". I expect "Headings" formula would:
Finds out what data has been selected by the user.
From that data: outputs an array into the cells below it which has the headings of the selected data.
e.g. Group 1 contains: A, B
Group 2 contains: C, D
Group 3 contain: E, F
If the user selects: "A", "B" and "E". "Headings" formula should output "Group 1" and "Group 3".
If the user selects "F" and "C". "Headings" should output "Group 2" and "Group 3"

Does that clarify? Apologies if not.

Comment: If the above clarification isn't enough:
In the spreadsheet, see "Extracting Selected Data" I2:I3 for an example of an expected output with the current data selected in B2:B

Comment: Added two solutions for "Headings". Please note that for the latter one, `|` should not be contained in the criteria, otherwise you need to escape it.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN({IF(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:E),,9^9)))="",,
 F2&" "&A2:A), B2:E}), "where Col1<>''"))
```

[image]

and:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN({IF(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(
 REGEXEXTRACT('Dynamic data'!B2:E, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B)))),,
 9^9)))="",,'Dynamic data'!F2&" "&'Dynamic data'!A2:A), IFNA(
 REGEXEXTRACT('Dynamic data'!B2:E, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B)))}), "where Col1<>''"))
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried implementing your solution to problem 2 into my main spreadsheet, however, it is giving me a "#REF!" error in the first cell, and the cell underneath it, and I don't understand the code well enough to troubleshoot it, as there is no popup box describing the error :\